# How to get source file name from its executable via plan9port db(1) unility?

Tags: plan-9

Moving to `plan9port` utilites I can't get used of `src` utility for executables (for scripts it works fine). It refers to `db(1)` to get a source file-name from executable in the following way:

```
% echo 'main?z' | db $1 | <some staff>
```

where `$1` is an executable program name and `main?z` a special instruction to `db(1)` debugger to print the file-name with function `main`.

But in my version of linux (Ubuntu) it doesn't works. db(1) do not produce a file-name, - it just prints the name of procedure: `main()` and no sources info.

I've tried to compile with `9c -n` (I think `-n` prevents compiler from stripping the code) with no luck.

Comment: Debugging secion at https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/plan9c.html gives more ideas to check. Will try..

Answer (score 0):

DWARF-2 is the key:

```
$ 9c -gdwarf-2 wc.c -o wc.o
$ 9l wc.o -o wc
$ echo 'p9main?z' | db wc
wc: linux 386 executable
no dt_debug section
p9main?                 p9main() /home/egor/plan9port/src/cmd/wc.c:21
```